# React - Random position every time the same picture renders

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Every time I press a button, the same picture has to be rendered in the DOM. This picture should have a random `top` value position every time it renders.
I am using `Math.random()` but the initial random number doesn't change. For example, if I refresh the page and I get 30 as random number, this number will be the same for each picture

Here is what I have tried:

```js
let top = Math.floor(Math.random()*50)

const ChipStyles = {
   position: 'absolute',
   top: top,
   left: '50%',
   transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
}

const Image = () => {
   return (
     <img src={myImg} style={ChipStyles} alt="" />
   )
}

export default Image
```

Comment: You need to generate your top value within the Image component

Comment: @Chris How do I do that?

Comment: `top value position every time it renders` - what does this actually mean? Every time you click the button you want a new random top position? Could you explain it better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your current set up, your `top` value will always be the same, no matter how many Image components you create. If you want a different top value, then you will need to generate a new top value for every Image component. You can do so using the below code.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
    
const Image = () => {
   const ChipStyles = useRef({
       position: 'absolute',
       top: Math.floor(Math.random()*50),
       left: '50%',
       transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)'
   });

   return (
     <img src={myImg} style={ChipStyles.current} alt=""}/>
   )
}
    
export default Image
```

This example uses the Ref object, which stores the value on its `current` property. Refs will not change from one render to the next, whereas a regular object would.

According to their documentation:

> This works because useRef() creates a plain JavaScript object. The only difference between useRef() and creating a {current: ...} object yourself is that useRef will give you the same ref object on every render.

See [Reactjs useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) from their official documentation for more information.

**EDIT**

This originally used `useMemo`, however as Adam pointed out, useMemo is not as reliable and is better for performance optimizations rather than storing values.

Comment: would it simpler to keep the top variable in the parent and make it a state instead of a js variable?

Comment: @Dheeraj given what he is trying to accomplish, putting it as state wouldn't be a very good way to go. State is used for variables that you may need to update later that will need to cause a component to render again. If your variable doesn't need to cause a render, then there isn't really a reason to use it as state. He also needed this value to be different for every Image component that renders, so keeping it in the parent wouldn't work for that either unless you generate a whole bunch of top values.

Comment: This may fail and end up being really hard to debug - `useMemo` is for performance optimizations, not logic. From the linked docs: `You may rely on useMemo as a performance optimization, **not as a semantic guarantee**` - using a ref is safer.

Comment: You're right @Adam, I'll update my answer to reflect this. useMemo was the first thing to come to mind as I've used it before, but it was for a different use case where I actually had to compute a new value based on a given props value.

Comment: @Chris apologies for asking so late, why was the OP's solution not working? would't it work if we simply move the `ChipStyles` and `top` inside `Image` component? you are using `useRef`and previously `useMemo` to set value once ie on mount, is't that unnecessarily complex? sorry again im a new to this

Comment: @pinchboitriggeredaf it's too much to explain here. Let's continue in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220591/react-random-position-every-time-the-same-picture-renders-chris

Comment: @Adam ref is for imperative programming is't it? where you would want to directly manipulate the dom. a constructor would have been the ideal place

Comment: @user5212263 you don’t need useEffect at all, you can provide the initial value to useState and use it. This approach is fine too. The reason I chose ref is because the value 1. never needs to be updated and 2. does therefore not need to be tied to the component’s lifecycle in anyway after mounting. This makes ref make more sense - state implies something that can change, but like I said, a state variable where you never use the setter would work fine too